# How do I disable spell checking in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

In Thunderbird, when I compose a new message, I can go into Options and unselect "Spell Check As You Type".  I have to do this every time I send a message.  How can I disable it permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Edit > Preferences > Composition > Spelling (tab) > "Enable spell check as you type"

[image: Thunderbird settings screenshot]

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  i don't have a Preferences item in my menu.  mu menu has File / Edit / View / Go / Message / Tools / Help.  this is thunderbird version 52.9.1 on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: oops.  i found it.  Edit / Preferences.  fixed now, many thanks.